# Metal clad cable: are there any useful residential applications?

Tags: electrical, wiring, nec

MC cable is touted as a secure one. But when I look closely at its possible uses inside a residence (according to NEC code), I can see none. In all protected areas (like inside the walls), NM cable cable like Romex can be used. In all areas where cable needs protection, a rigid conduit is required (and wires inside don't need to be MC).

Are there any areas inside the house where MC cable can be actually beneficial (able to provide savings while being code-compliant)?

Comment: I *think* the question is MC is unnecessarily expensive to use in walls, not sufficient for physical protection outside walls, and so apparently is useful mainly in non residential?  It's that so or are there home uses?

Comment: @jay613 - yes, you summarized it right. I wonder if there are any home uses for MC.

Answer (score 11):

Places where you'd rather not have the NM cable nibbled on by rodents. Having seen enough stripped-to-the-copper NM in remodeling, I'm not a fan of the stuff, given that "There are no mice in **my** house!" tends to be more wishful thinking than reality.

A circuit where you'd rather use a (less expensive, generally) AFCI at the first outlet rather than a (more expensive, generally) AFCI breaker, so it needs to be run in metal from the breaker to the first outlet.

Comment: Or there might be no mice *only until your cat dies*.

Comment: Having had a _cat_ chew on wiring (until he got all the way through and did himself in), I'd have to fully support this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Power to a residential electric hot water heater.

Some local codes/regulations require the use of it for certain devices/appliances, usually furnaces/heaters.

Comment: How can this not be solved by other cables?

Comment: @vidarlo  Some local codes require the use of it for certain devices/appliances, usually furnaces/heaters.

Comment: @gnicko **No**. You are **abusing** "not an answer". "Power to a residential electric hot water heater" **absolutely** is **an answer** to the question "Are there any useful residential applications for MC cable". It may or may not be *correct*, but if you think it is not helpful, the proper action is downvoting, not abusing flags.

Comment: @nobody Check the edit history, Sport.

Comment: I already did. The edits do not change anything. The initial revision unquestionably was **an answer**. Marking that "not an answer" was abusive. "Not an answer" is for things like "I have this problem too", follow-up questions, OP info that belongs in the question, etc.